# Serializer not passing complete information to API view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I created a serializer which the "user" below is from another Serializer which i imported, now the imported serializer(PubliceProfileSerializer) works fine on its own but it does not display the content of USER when i call it my browser from this serializer. Every other item shows except the user. Please help

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from users.api.serializers import PublicProfileSerializer
from blog.models import Post

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = PublicProfileSerializer(source='users.profile', read_only=True) 
    category = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    label = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
    
    def get_category(self, obj):
        return obj.get_category_display()

    def get_label(self, obj):
        return obj.get_label_display()
```

Answer (score 1):

Add you your serializer the list of fields. Replace

```
fields = '__all__'
```

with

```
fields = ('id', 'user', 'category', 'label')
```

because:

```
fields = '__all__'
```

will only populate `id`, `category`  and `label` from the **Post** model, but will not provide the nested user serializer, so it becomes:

```
class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ('id', 'user', 'category', 'label')
```

or

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = PublicProfileSerializer(many=False, 
                                   source='users.profile', 
                                   read_only=True) 
    category = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    label = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'category', 'label')

    def get_category(self, obj):
        return obj.get_category_display()

    def get_label(self, obj):
        return obj.get_label_display()
```

Comment: [
    {
        "id": 47,
        "category": "Music",
        "label": "PopSocial"
    },
    {
        "id": 42,
        "category": "Food",
        "label": "PopSocial"
    },
    {
        "id": 43,
        "category": "Food",
        "label": "PopSocial"
    }
] ..... this is all i get, I dont see the "user" there